# Is there a Grolsch flip-top bottle shortage?

Tags: equipment, bottles

This is a little off-topic to the process, but more about supplies for the process.

I thought I could pick up some cheap, used, Grolsch bottles online, until I started looking at the prices.  On Etsy and eBay, these used, empty bottles are going for almost the same price for a single bottle ($15.50 for a pair; $21 for three), as a new 4-pack ($7.20-9.50), with beer in them.  When you add on the shipping, and the wait, it'd actually be cheaper for me to run out to the store, buy a 4-pack, and empty the beer, for the bottles.  Is it that there's so much demand for these bottles, with more home brewers, that there's a shortage?

Where do most people go, for affordable, fermentation-strong, flip-tops?

Comment: If you have a brew supply retailer available, I think it would be cheaper just to order the bottles, they're usually ~20 USD for a case of 12, [here](https://www.homebrewing.org/16-oz-Amber-Flip-Top-Bottles--Case-of-12-_p_9733.html)  for example. But..you don't get beer inside them to drink :)

Comment: https://beercomics.com/comics/professional-beer-drinker.html

Comment: Where are you based?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a quick search for wholesale suppliers, some of these come in case of 12 - https://www.kinnek.com/industry/brewery/beer-bottles/?npc=3&page=1&sortby=relevance&tag=2197&bnode=22&source_detail=search

Hope that helps.

Comment: I don't think I bottle enough for home use, to order wholesale, but that's still a great site.  Thanks for sending it!

Comment: You may be surprised how small orders some suppliers will handle, always worth dropping them a line.